# Question got filtered by ignored tags even though it shouldn't as there are no matching tag (or wildcard tag)

Tags: bug, tags, wildcard

The question [How do i add an Extra JsonProperty to an existing JsonDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67658408/how-do-i-add-an-extra-jsonproperty-to-an-existing-jsondocument) has/had as of writing this post the following tags:

- [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)
- [system.text.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system.text.json)

I have several ignored tags configured, including wildcards. This question got filtered by my selection of ignored tags. However I cannot see any entry in my ignored tags list which would match one of these tags (but I have the tag [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) on my watch list, so at least the question got highlighted with a yellow background). This means the question got filtered out even though it shouldn't.

Why was this question filtered out and where was my mistake in my ignored tags list? Which entry was responsible in filtering the question out (and why)?

These are the wildcard tags I'm currently using in my ignore tags list:

```
*.js
*android
*angular*
*aws
*ios
*js
*python*
*wordpress*
amazon*
android*
angular*
apple*
azure*
c++*
cakephp*
cassandra*
codeigniter*
drupal*
facebook*
google-cloud*
joomla*
kentico*
laravel*
magento*
matlab*
nopcommerce-*
odoo*
opencart*
phpstorm*
prestashop*
py*
python*
reactjs*
sap-*
shopify*
slack*
spring*
swift*
symfony*
travis*
typo*
```

This is the complete list of ignored tags I'm using:

```
*.js
*android
*angular*
*aws
*ios
*js
*python*
*wordpress*
2sxc
3cx
3dsmax
6502
68hc11
aapt
abap
abaqus
ab-initio
abp
ace-editor
acl
acrobat
acrobat-sdk
actions-on-google
activecampaign
activecollab
activemq
activemq-artemis
activereports
activiti
acumatica
ada
adaptive-cards
adb
adminer
adminlte
admob
adobe-brackets
adobe-illustrator
adobe-indesign
adsense
advanced-custom-fields
advanceddatagrid
aem
aerospike
aframe
agda
ag-grid
agouti
aiml
airflow
airsim
ajax
ajv
akka
alamofire
aleagpu
alexa
alexa-skills-kit
alfresco
allennlp
alloy
allure
alm
amadeus
amazon*
amazon-advertising-api
amazon-athena
amazon-cloudformation
amazon-cloudfront
amazon-cognito
amazon-dynamodb
amazon-ecs
amazon-elb
amazon-iam
amazon-kinesis
amazon-rds
amazon-redshift
amazon-sns
amazon-sqs
ambari
amcharts
amibroker
amp-html
ampl
anaconda
android
android*
angular
angular*
anova
ansible
ansible-2.x
ant
antd
antlr4
anychart
anylogic
apache-arrow
apache-aurora
apache-beam
apache-camel
apache-cayenne
apache-flink
apache-hudi
apache-kafka
apache-kafka-streams
apache-nifi
apache-pig
apache-poi
apache-spark
apache-spark-sql
apex
apexcharts
apify
apigee
apktool
aplpy
apollo
apollo-client
apostrophe-cms
app-inventor
appium
appium-android
appkit
apple*
apple-developer
apple-sign-in
appveyor
aql
aqueduct
ar.js
arangodb
arcgis
arcore
arduino-uno
arena-simulation
argoproj
argo-workflows
aria2
arkit
arm
armeria
artifactory
artillery
asciidoctor
asio
aspectj
aspose
asterisk
at-command
atg
atom-editor
atomic-design
attiny
audacity
audiokit
aurelia
autocad
autodesk-forge
autohotkey
autoit
autosar
autosys
ava
avaloniaui
avaya
avd
avr
avro
avsc
awesome-wm
aws-batch
aws-cdk
aws-cli
aws-code-deploy
aws-lambda
aws-transcribe
axapta
axios
azerothcore
azure*
azure-data-explorer
babeljs
babylonjs
backpack-for-laravel
ballerina
bamboo
basic
bazel
bbc-microbit
bbedit
beautifulsoup
beyondcompare
bigbluebutton
bigcartel
bigcommerce
bigdata
biml
binance
bing-maps
bing-search
biopython
bi-publisher
birt
bison
bitbucket
bitcoinj
bitmex
bitrix
bixby
biztalk
blackberry
blackboard
blazor
blazor-server-side
blockly
blogger
bluepill
blueprism
bluetooth-lowenergy
bluez
bokeh
boomla
bootstrap-4
bootstrap-5
bootstrap-datepicker
bootstrap-datetimepicker
bootstrap-modal
bootstrap-table
bootstrap-vue
bosh
botframework
boto3
bots.business
boxfuse
bpf
braintree
branch.io
brave-browser
brightway
browserify
brython
bsmultiselect
bucklescript
buddypress
build.gradle
buildozer
bukkit
bulma
business-objects
byebug
byte-buddy
c
c++
c++*
c++14
c++20
c++builder
c++-winrt
c11
c99
caddy
cadence
cadence-workflow
cakebuild
cakephp
cakephp*
cakephp-2.x
calendly
camunda
can-bus
canoe
canvas-lms
capacitor
capl
capybara
carousel
cartodb
cassandra*
cdk8s
cefsharp
celery
centos7
centos8
ceph
cesium
cgo
chapel
chef-infra
cherrypy
chicken-scheme
chisel
chocolatey
chromebook
chromecast
chrome-remote-desktop
cinema-4d
circleci
citrix
civicrm
ckeditor4.x
clang
clang++
clang-format
clearcase
clearquest
clearscript
clickhouse
clingo
clio-api
clion
clips
clojurescript
cloudant
cloud-foundry
cloudinary
cloudkit
clover
clrmd
cmdlet
cobol
cobra
cockroachdb
cocoa
cocoapods
cocos2d-js
codeanywhere
codeblocks
codeception
codeigniter
codeigniter*
codeigniter-3
codemirror
codenameone
coderunner
codesandbox
codesys
codewarrior
cognos
coinbase-api
coldfusion-11
common-lisp
composer-php
conan
concourse
concrete5
concur
conda
condor
confluent-platform
connman
contact-form-7
contiki
cookiecutter
coq
corda
cordova-plugins
core-bluetooth
coredns
coreml
cornerstone
coronasdk
cortex-m
couchbase
countif
coursera-api
cpanel
cplex
cppcheck
cql
craftcms
crashlytics
crawler4j
crm
cryptojs
crystal-lang
cs50
cs-cart
csh
css
ctest
ctypes
cuba-platform
cucm
cucumber-jvm
cupy
cursive
cvxpy
cyberduck
cybersource
cycript
cypress
cython
cytoscape
d
dafny
daml
dapr
dart
dask
dask-distributed
dat.gui
databricks
datadog
datastage
dataweave
datomic
dax
dayjs
dbt
debezium
delphi
delphi-10.1-berlin
delphi-2009
delphi-6
deno
detours
detox
devextreme
devstack
dhall
dialogflow-cx
dialogflow-es
digital-ocean
direct3d11
directus
directx-12
discord
discord.js
discord.net
discord.py
discord.py-rewrite
discord-jda
disqus
django
django-oscar
django-rest-framework
django-urls
dji-sdk
dl4j
dm-script
docker
dockerfile
docker-swarm
docusaurus
docusignapi
docx4j
dolphindb
doorkeeper
dotnetnuke
dplyr
draftjs
drake
drake-r-package
drone
drools
dropbear
druid
drupal
drupal*
dsc
dsharp+
duckdb
duktape
dulwich
dwoo
dynamics-365
dynamics-business-central
dynamics-crm
dynamodb-queries
easy68k
easy-digital-downloads
easypost
ebay-api
ebpf
echarts
ecmascript-6
ecto
eiffel
eigen
eigen3
ejabberd
ejs
elassandra
￼elasticsearch
￼elasticsearch-api
elasticsearch-high-level-restclient
￼elasticsearch-painless
￼elasticsearch-rails
electron
element-ui
eleventy
elf
elfinder
elgg
elisp
elixir
elk
elki
elm
eloquent
embedded-linux
emeditor
emq
emscripten
envoyproxy
eon
epplus
erlang-supervisor
errbit
es6-modules
eslint
esp32
esp8266
esper
esxi
eto
eucalyptus
eve
event-b
eventstoredb
eviews
exact-online
excel
excel-2010
excel-2016
excel-addins
excel-dna
excel-formula
exchange-server
exchangewebservices
exist-db
expect
expo
express
expressionengine
extendscript
extjs4.2
ezsql
f#-giraffe
f5
fabricjs
facebook*
factor-lang
falconframework
fancybox-3
fasm
fast-ai
fastapi
fastify
fastlane
fastreport
fat-free-framework
faunadb
fb-hydra
feathersjs
featuretools
fedora
fetch-api
filepond
finatra
fipy
firebase
firebase-admin
firebase-cloud-messaging
firebase-hosting
firebase-realtime-database
firebase-storage
firebase-tools
firebird
firefox-addon-webextensions
firemonkey
fiware-orion
flash
flask-security
flexbox
flow-framework
flowtype
fluentd
fluent-ui
fluid-framework
flume
flurry
flutter
flutter2.0
flutter-dependencies
flutter-layout
flutter-test
fluxcd
flysystem
flyte
flyway
folium
formik
formio
forth
fortran90
fortran95
foundry-code-repositories
foundry-code-workbooks
foundry-data-connection
foursquare
fpdf
fpga
fp-ts
frama-c
freebsd
freemarker
freepascal
freeradius
frida
froala
fstar
fuelcms
fullcalendar
fuseki
fxml
g1ant
gambas
game-maker
game-maker-studio-2
ganache
garrys-mod
gatling
gatsby
gcloud
gdscript
geant4
geany
geb
geckofx
gee
gekko
gem5
genexus
gensim
genymotion
geode
geopandas
gerrit
getgauge
getorgchart
getstream-io
getusermedia
gf
gforth
gfortran
ghc
ghdl
gherkin
ghostscript
github3.py
github-actions
gitlab
gitlab-ci
gitversion
giza++
glidejs
global-payments-api
glsl
gmail-api
gml
gmsplacepicker
gnuplot
go
godaddy-api
godot
go-ethereum
go-gin
gojs
goland
google-admin-sdk
google-ads-api
google-alerts
google-analytics-api
google-app-maker
google-apps-script
google-assistant-sdk
google-bigquery
google-calendar-api
google-cast
google-cast-sdk
google-chrome-devtools
google-chrome-os
google-classroom
google-cloud*
google-cloud-firestore
google-cloud-memorystore
google-cloud-platform
google-cloud-shell
google-colaboratory
google-compute-engine
google-contacts-api
google-coral
google-custom-search
google-data-studio
google-docs-api
google-drive-api
google-finance
google-identity
google-kubernetes-engine
google-location-services
google-mlkit
googlemock
google-my-business-api
google-pagespeed
google-people
google-places-api
google-play-console
google-sheets
google-sheets-api
google-sheets-formula
google-slides
google-smart-home
google-tag-manager
google-text-to-speech
google-translate
google-vision
google-workspace
gosu
go-templates
gp
graaljs
gradle
gradle-kotlin-dsl
gradle-plugin
grafana
grandstack
graphite
graphql
graphql-js
grav
gravityforms
graylog
greendao
greenplum
gremlin
grib-api
griddb
groff
grpc
grpc-web
gruntjs
gsap
gsoap
gspread
gstreamer
gtk3
gtsummary
guava
guidewire
gulp
gulp-karma
gun
gurobi
guzzle
guzzle6
gwt-openlayers
h2
h2o
h3
h5py
hacklang
hadoop
hadoop2
hakyll
hal
halcon
halide
hana
handsontable
hangfire
haproxy
hashicorp-vault
haskell
haskell-stack
hasura
haxe
hazelcast
hbase
here-api
hexo
highslide
hive
hiveql
homebrew
hook-woocommerce
hootsuite
hotchocolate
hp-uft
html-framework-7
htmx
httr
huawei-mobile-services
hugo
hy
hybris
hyperledger
hyperledger-composer
hyperledger-fabric
hyperledger-sawtooth
i2c
iar
ibm-cloud
ibm-doors
ibm-integration-bus
ibm-midrange
ibm-mq
ibp-vscode-extension
iccube-reporting
icecast
ida
idempiere
identityserver4
idris
ifttt
ignite
imacros
imdbpy
impala
inappbrowser
infinispan
influxdb
influxql
infor-eam
informatica
informatica-powercenter
innerhtml
inno-setup
instagram
instagram-api
install4j
instamojo
instana
integromat
intel-edison
intelephense
intellij-plugin
intersection-observer
intuit
inversifyjs
ionic3
ionic4
ionic-framework
ios
ios13
ipa
iperf
iphone
ipython
isabelle
istio
itext
itext7
itfoxtec-identity-saml2
itunes
iverilog
ivr
j
jackrabbit
janusgraph
jasmine
jasperserver
javacard
javalite
javascript
javascript-objects
javers
jaws-screen-reader
jbpm
jedis
jekyll
jelastic
jena
jenkins-job-dsl
jenkins-pipeline
jestjs
jfugue
jhipster
jimp
jinja2
jinjava
jint
jira
jira-plugin
jira-rest-api
jison
jjwt
jmespath
jmeter
jodit
joi
jointjs
jolt
jomsocial
joomla
joomla*
jooq
jose
jpgraph
jq
jql
jquery
jquery-focusout
jquery-isotope
jquery-select2
jqwidget
jsch
jscript
jsdoc
jsgrid
jsonata
json-ld
jspdf
jsviews
jsx
julia
jupyter
jupyterhub
jupyter-notebook
jxl
jxls
jython
kafka-consumer-api
kaggle
kaizala
kali-linux
kapacitor
karate
karel
karma-jasmine
karma-mocha
karma-runner
katex
kdb
kedro
keil
kendo-react-ui
kentico
kentico*
keras
kerberos
kestrel
keycloak
keystonejs
kframework
kie
kinect
kitti
kivy
kiwi-tcms
klee
kml
knex.js
knitr
koa
kodi
kofax
kogito
kohana
koin
kong
konva
konvajs
korge
kotest
kotlin
kotlin-coroutines
kotlin-native
kql
ksh
ksqldb
ktor
kubectl
kubernetes
kubernetes-helm
kubernetes-ingress
kuka-krl
kurento
labelimg
labview
laminas
lapack
laravel
laravel*
laravel-5
lc3
ld
leaflet
lean
leanback
lerna
less
lex
libimobiledevice
libreoffice-base
libreoffice-basic
libreoffice-calc
librosa
libstdc++
liferay-6.2
lighthouse
limesurvey
linguijs
linkedin
linker-errors
linkki
linphone
liquibase
liquid
little-man-computer
llblgen
lldb
llvm
loadrunner
locust
lodash
logstash
lolcode
lombok
loopback4
loopbackjs
lora
lottie
lotus
lotus-notes
luajit
lumen
lunrjs
lwc
lxc
m4
maatwebsite-excel
macos
macos-catalina
macvlan
magento*
magnolia
mailgun
mailkit
mainframe
makefile
mallet
mamp
mandrill
mantis
mapbender3
mapbox
mapbox-gl
mapbox-gl-js
maple
mapstruct
marie
markdown
marklogic
masm
materialize
material-ui
mathjax
matlab*
matlab-guide
matomo
matter.js
maxima
maximo
maxscale
mdt
mdx
mean-stack
mechanicalturk
media-queries
mediatr
mediawiki
mediawiki-extensions
medium.com
medoo
membrane-soa
mendeley
mendix
mercury
mern
meshlab
mesibo
mesos
metafor
metal
metamask
metatrader5
metpy
micronaut
microsoft-graph-api
microsoft-graph-plannertasks
microsoft-teams
microsoft-translator
microstrategy
mifare
minecraft
minecraft-forge
minikanren
minikube
minio
minitab
minizinc
mips
mirth
mitmproxy
mit-scheme
mit-scratch
mixpanel
ml.net
mlr
mlr3
mmenu
mmix
mobx
mocha.js
modelica
modula-2
moleculer
momentjs
monaco-editor
mongodb
mongodb-compass
mongoose
mongoose-middleware
mono.cecil
monogame
monolog
moodle
mountebank
moviepy
mpich
mql4
mql5
mqtt
ms-access
ms-access-2013
ms-access-2016
msal
ms-media-foundation
msmq
ms-office
msp430
ms-word
mt4
mule
mule4
mulesoft
mutation-testing
mxgraph
mxnet
mybatis
mypy
mysql-python
nand2tetris
nashorn
nasm
nativescript
nativescript-angular
nativescript-vue
nearley
nearprotocol
nestjs
netbeans
netezza
netflix
netflix-eureka
netlify
netlogo
netsuite
networkx
neutralinojs
newrelic
nexmo
nextcloud
nginx-ingress
ngrok
ngrx
nicescroll
niftynet
nightmare
nim-lang
nivo-slider
nix
nltk
node-jose
nodemailer
nodemcu
node-red
node-sqlite3
nopcommerce
nopcommerce-*
normalizr
npgsql
npm
nrwl-nx
ns2
ns-3
nsis
nswag
numba
nunjucks
nutch
nuxeo
nuxt.js
obiee
objectbox
objective-c
objective-c++
ocaml
occi
ocelot
octave
octobercms
octopus
odata
odoo*
office365
office-addins
office-interop
office-js
office-scripts
office-store
office-ui-fabric-react
okhttp
omnet++
omnipay
onedrive
onenote-api
onesignal
one-simulator
onnx
oozie
opa
opalrb
opayo
opcache
opc-ua
openai-gym
openbmc
opencart
opencart*
opencart-3
opencascade
opencl
openedge
openedx
openfl
openid-connect
openlayers
openlayers-5
openlayers-6
openldap
openmdao
openmeetings
openmp
openpdf
openproject
openpyxl
openresty
openshift
openstack
openstack4j
opentap-proj
opentk
opentok
openvino
optaplanner
optuna
opus
oracle
oracle12c
oracle-apex
oracle-aq
oracle-golden-gate
oracle-pro-c
oracle-sqldeveloper
orange
orbeon
orchardcms
org-mode
￼ormlite-servicestack
orocommerce
orocrm
or-tools
osascript
osclass
oscommerce
osmnx
osmosis
otrs
outlook-addin
p5.js
packer
pact
pagerduty
pagespeed
pagespeed-insights
paho
palantir-foundry
pandas
pandoc
pantheon
paperjs
paraview
parceljs
pari-gp
parquet
parsec
parse-server
pascal
pascalscript
passenger
passport-saml
patroni
paw-app
pawn
payara
payment
payment-gateway
payment-processing
paypal-rest-sdk
paytm
pbs
pchart
pdb
pdfbox
pdflatex
pdfmake
peerjs
pegjs
pelican
pentaho
peoplecode
peoplesoft
pepper
perfino
perforce
perl
pervasive
pfsense
pgadmin
pgadmin-4
pgi
pg-promise
phalcon
phantomjs
phaser
phaser-framework
phing
phinx
phoenix
photon
photoshop-script
phpbb3
phpexcel
phpfox
phpmailer
php-phantomjs
phpspreadsheet
phpstorm
phpstorm*
phpword
physx
picasso
pickle
pine-script
pinvoke
pip
pipedrive-api
pipenv
plaid
plasticscm
playwright
plc
plesk
plivo
plotly
plotly-dash
plotly-python
plots.jl
plpgsql
plsql
plyr
pm2
pocketpc
poco-libraries
podio
polarion
polymer
polymer-2.x
pos
postgis
postgresql
postgresql-12
postgresql-9.5
postman
postscript
pouchdb
powerapps
power-automate
powerbi
powerbi-desktop
powerbuilder
powerdesigner
powerdns
powerpivot
powerpoint
powerquery
powershell-5.0
pptxgenjs
praat
precision-recall
premake
prestashop*
presto
primeng
prism
prisma
prisma-graphql
prismjs
processing
processmaker
processwire
progress-4gl
progressive-web-apps
prolog
promela
prometheus
prometheus-alertmanager
prometheus-operator
promql
propel2
protocol-buffers
protractor
proxmox
psql
psychopy
psycopg2
pug
pulumi
puppet
puppeteer
purescript
purrr
pusher
pvlib
py*
py2neo
pyarrow
pyautogui
pybind11
pycharm
pycrypto
pydatalog
pydev
pydicom
pyenv
pyfcm
pygame
pygithub
pyglet
pygments
pyhook
pyinotify
pyinstaller
pylint
pymc
pymc3
pymongo
pymysql
pyomo
pyopenssl
pyparsing
pypika
pyppeteer
pypy
pyqt4
pyqt5
pyranges
pyrevit
pyroot
pysal
pysam
pyscripter
pysdl2
pyserial
pyshark
pyside2
pysimplegui
pysnmp
pyspark
pystan
pytest
pyth-lang
python
python*
python-3.7
python-requests
python-sphinx
pytorch
pyttsx
pyvisa
pyviz
pyvmomi
pywinauto
pyyaml
pyzmq
q#
qaf
qbasic
qemu
qliksense
qlikview
qml
qt5
qtabwidget
qt-creator
quandl
quanteda
quarkus
quasar-framework
questdb
quickbooks
quickfix
quill
r
r.net
rabbitmq
racket
ractivejs
raft
raku
rally
raml
rancher
rasa
rasa-nlu
rascal
raspberry-pi
raspberry-pi3
ratchet
ravendb
razorpay
r-caret
rcpp
rdf
rdlc
react-admin
react-apollo
react-bootstrap
react-hook-form
reactjs
reactjs*
react-jsonschema-forms
react-leaflet
react-map-gl
react-native
react-native-maps
react-native-navigation
react-navigation
react-proptypes
react-router
react-spring
react-table
react-testing-library
realm
rebol
recaptcha
recharts
red
red5
redhawksdr
redux
redux-observable
redux-saga
redux-thunk
re-frame
relayjs
remote-desktop
renpy
rescript
rest-assured
rethinkdb
retrofit
retrofit2
reveal.js
revit-api
r-exams
rfid
rhadoop
rhapsody
rider
ringcentral
riot
riscv
r-lavaan
r-mapedit
r-markdown
roblox
robo3t
robocopy
robotframework
rocket.chat
roku
rollupjs
ros
rpgle
r-plotly
r-ranger
r-raster
rscript
rselenium
rstudio
rstudio-server
rtf
rtools
rtsp
ruby-2.0
rubymine
rubymotion
ruby-on-rails
ruby-on-rails-5
ruby-on-rails-6
rundeck
rust
rust-cargo
rvest
rxdart
rxjs
rx-py
rx-swift
ryu
s4hana
sabre
sage
sails.js
saleor
salesforce
salesforce-commerce-cloud
salesforce-communities
salesforce-lightning
salt-stack
sap
sap-*
sapb1
sap-cloud-foundry
sap-cloud-platform
sap-cloud-sdk
sap-data-dictionary
sap-dotnet-connector
sap-erp
sap-gui
sapjco3
sapper
saprfc
sapui5
sas
sas-jmp
saxon
sbt
scala
scalaz
scapy
scenekit
scichart
scikit-learn
scilab
scons
scrapy
screeps
seaborn
searchkick
segue
selenium-chromedriver
selenium-ide
sendgrid
sendwithus
sentry
sequelize.js
sequelize-typescript
serenity-js
serilog
￼servicestack
service-worker
sgx
sh
shacl
shake-build-system
sharepoint-2013
sharepoint-2016
sharepoint-online
sheetjs
shibboleth
shiny
shinydashboard
shiro
shopify*
shopizer
shopware
siddhi
sidekiq
signalr
silvershop
silverstripe
simd
simpy
singlestore
sinon
sirishortcuts
sitecore
sitecore8
sitefinity
skia
skype
slack*
slick-3.0
slim
slim-3
slim-4
slingr
slurm
smali
smalltalk
smartcontracts
smil
sml
smlnj
snakemake
snaplogic
snipcart
snowflake-cloud-data-platform
snowpack
socket.io
socrata
solace
solidity
solidworks
solrj
sonarcloud
sonarqube
soot
soql
soundcloud
sox
spacemacs
spacy
spark-ar-studio
sparql
spartacus-storefront
spatstat
spfx
sphinx
splunk
spotfire
spotify
spree
spring*
sprite-kit
spss
spyder
spyne
sql-loader
sqlplus
sqlyog
sqoop
square-connect
ssas
sse
sshpass
st
stackblitz
stackdriver
stackify
stanford-nlp
stargazer
stata
steamworks-api
stellar
stenciljs
step
stimulsoft
stm32
stm32f4
stm32f4discovery
stocktwits
stormcrawler
storybook
strapi
stripe-payments
structr
stylus
sublimetext
sublimetext3
substrate
sugarcrm
suitecommerce
suitecrm
suitescript
sulu
summernote
sumo
sumologic
supercollider
superpower
supervisord
svelte
svelte-3
svgpanzoom
swagger
swagger-codegen
swagger-ui
swashbuckle
sweetalert
sweetalert2
swift
swift*
swift3
swift4
swift5
swift-package-manager
swiftui
swiper
swi-prolog
sybase
sylius
symfony
symfony*
symfony-3.4
symfony4
symmetricds
sympy
sysml
systemc
system-verilog
system-verilog-assertions
tableau-api
tabulator
tailwind-css
talend
tally
tampermonkey
tapestry
tarantool
tasm
tastypie
tatsu
tcl
tcpdf
teamcity
teiid
telegram
telegram-bot
telegram-webhook
telerik-reporting
telethon
telosys
tensorboard
tensorflow
tensorflow.js
tensorflow2.0
tensorflow2.x
tensorflow-federated
tensorflow-lite
tensorflow-probability
tensorrt
teradata
termux
terraform
terragrunt
terser
tesseract
testcafe
testflight
textile
tf.keras
tfs-2015
tfvc
thelounge
thingsboard
thinkscript
thomson-reuters-eikon
three.js
thrift
thunderbird
thymeleaf
ti-basic
tibco
tidymodels
tidyr
timber
time-complexity
timescaledb
tinker
tinymce-5
tippyjs
tizen
tk
tla+
tmux
toit
torch
tosca
tradingview-api
traefik
travis*
trello
truffle
turbo-pascal
tvos
tweetinvi
twig
twilio
twilio-api
twilio-flex
twilio-functions
twilio-studio
twisted
twitter-bootstrap-3
twitter-bootstrap-wizard
typeorm
typescript
typescript2.0
typo*
typo3
uber-api
u-boot
uipath
umbraco
umbraco8
unetstack
uniface
unity3d
unityads
unityscript
unity-ui
unity-webgl
uno-platform
unpoly
unreal-engine4
usart
uwp
uwp-xaml
uwsgi
vaadin
vaex
vagrant
vagrantfile
vala
valgrind
vapor
varnish
vaticle-typeql
vavr
vb.net
vb.net-2010
vba
vbscript
vega-lite
veins
velo
velocity
veracode
vercel
verilog
vert.x
vespa
vhdl
vimeo
vimium
virtualbox
virtualenv
virtual-machine
virtualmin
virtuemart
visual-c++
visual-studio-code
visualsvn-server
vitess
vivado
vlang
vmware
vnc-server
volttron
vpc
vscode-calva
vscode-extensions
vsix
vtiger
vtk
vue.js
vue-cli
vuejs2
vuejs3
vue-native
vuepress
vue-router
vue-test-utils
vuetify.js
vulkan
vunit
w2ui
wagtail
wakanda
wap
watin
wavelet-transform
web.py
web2py
web3
webgl
webi
weblate
weblogic12c
webots
webpack
webrtc
websphere-liberty
webstorm
weka
weld
wfp
whatsapp
whmcs
wicket
wikidata
wikipedia-api
wildfly
windbg
windows-server-2019
winforms
winjs
wireguard
wiremock
wkhtmltopdf
wmi
woocommerce
woocommerce-rest-api
wordpress
workbox
workfusion
wso2
wt
wxwidgets
x86-16
x86-64
xamarin
xamarin.android
xamarin.forms
xamarin.ios
xamarin.mac
xamarin.uitest
xc16
xceed
xcframework
xcode9
xctest
xdebug
xenforo
xero-api
xl-deploy
xlsb
xlsxwriter
xpages
xstate
xtermjs
xtext
yacc
yaml
yammer
yarn
yarnpkg
yfinance
yii2
yoast
yocto
yolo
youtrack
youtube-data-api
youtube-iframe-api
youtube-livestreaming-api
yq
yubico
yugabyte-db
yum
yup
z3
z3py
z80
zabbix
zapier
zend-framework
zend-framework3
zenject
zeromq
zig
zigbee
zipline
zk
zkteco
zoho
zurb-foundation
zynq
```

Comment: Is it possible that the `*.js` is falsely catching the "system.text ***.js*** " portion of `system.text.json`? (Eg. https://regex101.com/r/OUjdNb/1) It wouldn't be working properly if that were the case, but it's a hunch nonetheless.